# Thymelaf block loosing style

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
<a href="/" class="logo logo_image">
    <span>
        <block >Plats</block>
        <span class="muellerhoff" >Bruts</span>
    </span>
    <img src="http://172.114.143.253:7080/images/logo.png" >
</a>
</div>
```

and I see this on the browser:

[image]

but when I use thymeleaf:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
    <a href="/" class="logo logo_image">
        <th:block th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}" />
        <span class="muellerhoff" th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name2')}"></span>
        <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" th:alt="${@environment.getProperty('site.name')}"  th:title="{@environment.getProperty('site.name')}">
    </a>
</div>
```

the style is lost:

[image]

and when I do view source I see this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
                            <a href="/" class="logo logo_image">
                                Plats
                                <span class="muellerhoff">Bruts</span>
                                <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" th:alt="${@environment.getProperty('site.name')}"  th:title="{@environment.getProperty('site.name')}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

I also tried `<block th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}" />` with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf [th:block](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag) is not the same as HTML tag `<block>`. If your first HTML snippet work as intended, enhancing it with Thymeleaf should look like the following...

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
<a href="/" class="logo logo_image">
    <span>
        <block th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name1')}">Plats</block>
        <span class="muellerhoff" th:text="${@environment.getProperty('site.name2')}">Bruts</span>
    </span>
    <img src="http://172.114.143.253:7080/images/logo.png" th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" th:alt="${@environment.getProperty('site.name')}"  th:title="{@environment.getProperty('site.name')}">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the `<block>` tag in HTML. How is it defined?

Comment: Hi @andrewjames, The HTML [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) doesn't have a definition for `<block>`, as of I can assume this is the [custom element](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) created by the author with maybe some styles applicable to it. Otherwise, this tag will be treated as regular `<span>`.  I have created the Thymeleaf example based on HTML markup which worked by definition of the question. I couldn't run it as it requires some CSS classes, which weren't posted. Hopefully, all the above would make science for you. Best regards,

Comment: Yes - that makes sense. Thank you for your notes. (I suspect the question should be using `<span>` instead of `<block>` - but that is just my guess.)

Comment: @andrewjames As I mention, I don't know, maybe the author has certain CSS styles applied to the tag directly, for example: `block {border: 1px dashed red; display: block;}`. I have just answered Thymeleaf question.